# gb4e glosses are not aligned properly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, gb4e

I am attempting a simple gloss (with translation) using the `gb4e` package. The relevant code is as follows (2 issues):

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex\label{myexample6}
\gll \textit{Mieleeni tulu er\"{a}s ajatus.}\\
mind-\textsc{ill}-\textsc{1pos} come-\textsc{impf}-\textsc{3sg} an idea\\
\trans 'An idea came into my mind.'\\
\end{exe}
```

and:

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex\label{myexample5}
\gll \textit{N\"{a}in tyt\"{o}n. Se tytt\"{o} itki.}\\
see-\textsc{impf}-\textsc{1sg} girl-\textsc{acc} it girl cry-\textsc{impf}-\textsc{(3sg)}\\
\trans 'I saw a girl. That girl was crying.'\\
\end{exe}
```

When I compile, there is a massive space in the gloss between the first and second elements (mind... and come../see... and girl...) with the result that it does not align at all with the line above it. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let `gb4e` read each word separately. By putting your whole text in the argument of `\textit`, you're preventing it from doing so. You could italicize each word separately, but `gb4e` provides a better way to set the format of the first gloss tier: Just put the following in your preamble.

```
\let\eachwordone=\textit
```

There are corresponding `\eachwordtwo` and `\eachwordthree` for the second and third tier (of `\glll`), respectively. You can then write your words without the extra brackets:

```
\gll Mieleeni tulu er\"{a}s ajatus.\\
mind-\textsc{ill-1pos} come-\textsc{impf-3sg} an idea\\
\trans `An idea came into my mind.'
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I should not have accepted that answer.